What does super().__init__() do when defining a class for custom exceptions?
I came across a piece of code which was meant to define a class for custom exception. What I do not understand is why there is a need to call and initiate error message of the parent Exception class because my understanding is that we take care of the message part by defining a custom message function . Specifically, I just want to know what happens for both the situations with and without that line of code.
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error_message, error_detail:sys):
        super().__init__(error_message)  # calling the parent class constructor
        self.error_message = error_message_details(error_message,error_detail)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.error_message

The function error_message_details is as follows:
def error_message_details(error, error_detail:sys):
    _,_,exc_tb = error_detail.exc_info()  # gets information about the exception from the interpreter
    file_name = exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
    lineNo = exc_tb.tb_lineno
    error_message = "error occured in script [{0}] on line number [{1}]; error message [{2}]".format(
        file_name,
        lineNo,
        str(error)
    )
    
    return error_message

I tried running the code with and without that line of code and when I omitted the line, the error message did not print at all and when I included the line it worked as it should. I just do not understand how this works.

"I tried running the code" - which code exactly? Were you printing the message yourself? Were you just raising the custom exception?

Without super().init(error_message), the CustomException class won't initialize the error message using the constructor of the parent Exception class. As a result, when an instance of CustomException is raised and converted to a string (e.g., when printed), it won't have an error message set by default. Therefore, when you try to print the exception, you won't see any error message.
